# What do I need to use the 'nub' function?

Tags: list, haskell

In the Data.list is set:

---

**"Set" operations**

```
nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

*O(n^2). The nub function removes duplicate elements from a list. In particular, it keeps only the first occurrence of each element. (The name nub means `essence'.) It is a special case of nubBy, which allows the programmer to supply their own equality test.*

---

I can't use this function directly. How do I use the function nub? Do I have to import something?

Comment: @May Read the edit to my answer, then unaccept it and accept Satvik's answer instead please.

Comment: Also, you [don't want to use the nub function](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-ordnub#dont-use-nub) in practice because it is (as you say) quadratic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever in doubt try [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=nub). It will tell you in which package the function is present and what module you need to import etc. You can also search function by types.

Answer (score 10):

`nub` isn't in [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html), it's in [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html).

```
import Data.List
```

---

**Edit:** I see you have accepted my answer. I also see that Satvik has posted a better answer. I shall explain.

In case you are not a native English speaker, I shall tell you that there is a saying:

> Give a man a fish, and he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish, and he will eat for the rest of his life.

- My answer was the give-a-man-a-fish answer: it answered your immediate question, but did nothing to help you with similar questions you may have in the future. Which module is `when` in? Which module is `on` in? Etc.
- Satvik's answer was the teach-a-man-to-fish answer: it told you how to answer your question yourself. It enabled you to answer not only your immediate question, but also future similar questions you will have. And it is better that you learn how to answer your own questions, because then your questions will be answered sooner. (And it is less effort for the rest of us.)

Comment: Really I was more annoyed that I hadn't posted the better answer myself.

Comment: Thanks @Gricey — now fixed.